# Wpf and Telnet Client

Tags: wpf, telnet

Hi 
my wpf application is using a other .exe for communicating with a server. this communication uses telnet. i know its not the best but i have to use it. my question is: does anyone know how to check the status of the telnet client or a was how to start (install) the client?

thanks for your help!

mfg chris

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to figure out from your application if telnet client is installed on a given machine (I also assume a Vista/Win7 scenario as XP contains the telnet client by default, whilest the new windows versions don't).

This MSDN documentation shows how you can install the telnet client from the command line [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28WS.10%29.aspx). Considering that you are invoking a package manager, I can logically assume that you should also be able to check wheter a package has already been installed, or if you try to install an already installed package the package manager will just ignore the request. If all else fails you can also check if certain registry keys exist (just google for telnet registrey keys).

To invoke the package manager from your app, you can use the System.Diagnostics.Process class.